# Tranfer image(jpg) pc to pc using TCP, Java

Tags: java, tcpclient, tcpserver

I want to transfer image(jpg) from one pc to another pc using TCP protocol. I have written server and client code. I have also got output with same file size as source image.However, it cannot be opened by the Windows imageviewer. I could not find the problem. Could you help me? Thank you.

Client code

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;

public class mytcpiclient 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {  
        try {

            Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 6000);
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(
                    socket.getOutputStream());
            //out.writeChar('I'); // as image,
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("D:\\image\\images1.jpg"));
            ByteArrayOutputStream ao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int read = 0;
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            while ((read = dis.read(buf)) > -1) {
                ao.write(buf, 0, read);
            }
            out.writeLong(ao.size());
            out.write(ao.toByteArray());
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            dis.close();
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

Server code

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;



public class mytcpserverimage 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
        try 
          {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(6000);

            System.out.println("Server started. Listening to the port 6000");


            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();


            byte[] mybytearray = new byte[10000000];   

            InputStream inputStream = clientSocket.getInputStream();
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("E:\\bbb.jpg");
            BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream);

            System.out.println("Receiving...");

            int bytesRead = inputStream.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
            int current = bytesRead;

            do {
                bytesRead = inputStream.read(mybytearray, current, (mybytearray.length - current));
                if (bytesRead >= 0) {
                    current += bytesRead;
                }
            } while (bytesRead > -1);


            bufferedOutputStream.write(mybytearray, 0, current);
            bufferedOutputStream.flush();
            bufferedOutputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();
            clientSocket.close();
            serverSocket.close();

            System.out.println("Sever recieved the file");



          }
          catch(Exception e)
          {
             System.out.print("Whoops! It didn't work!\n"+e);
          }
    }
}
```

SOLVED

client

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;

public class myclienttcpimage 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {  
        try
        {
            Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 6000);
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(
                    socket.getOutputStream());
            //out.writeChar('I'); // as image,
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("d:\\g.jpg"));
            ByteArrayOutputStream ao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int read = 0;
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            while ((read = dis.read(buf)) > -1) {
                ao.write(buf, 0, read);
            }
            out.writeLong(ao.size());
            out.write(ao.toByteArray());
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            dis.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Server

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;



public class mytcpserverimage 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
        try 
          {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(6000);

            System.out.println("Server started. Listening to the port 10898");


            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();


            //byte[] mybytearray = new byte[10000000];   

            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            //char c = dis.readChar();
            //if (c == 'I')
            {
                long length = dis.readLong();
                DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(
                        new FileOutputStream("e:\\aaa.jpg"));
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int len;
                while ((len = dis.read(buffer)) != -1) 
                {
                    dos.write(buffer, 0, len);
                }

                dis.close();
                dos.close();

            }
            System.out.println("Sever recieved the file");



            }
          catch(Exception e)
          {
             System.out.print("Whoops! It didn't work!\n"+e);
          }

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you think there's anything in your implementation that makes it unique to jpg files? Images as a whole? How about you try a text file? Then look at the content of the transferred text file... Your answer is there.

Comment: Does your assignment allow you to use the [Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) class?  Its `copy` methods would make your task easier by orders of magnitude.

Comment: The problem is solved. Thank you very much.